# Laravel 5 - Routing with optional prefixes

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I would appreciate some help with routing in Laravel 5.

I've got three models: ReasearchLine, ReasearchGroup and Publications.
Each ReasearchGroup belongs to a ReasearchLine. Each Publication can belong to a ReasearchLine and to a ReasearchGroup.

My db schema looks like this:

**research_lines** table:
id

**research_groups** table:
id,research_line_id (references id on research_lines)

**publications** table:
id,research_line_id (references id on research_lines),research_group_id (references id on research_groups)

So, I want my publications to be accessible by:

- `/research-group-slug/research-line-slug/publications`

  - show all publications belonging to the research line and the the research group
- `/research-line-slug/publications`

  - show all publications belonging to the research group
- `/publications`

  - show all publications

I was looking into Route prefixing in order to do this, but I'm not quite getting how can I set my prefixes as optional.

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing in laravel is as complicated as you make it,

```
Route::get('/', 'MyController@myFunction');
```

You pass parameters by using the curly brace syntax

```
Route::get('/segment/{id}' ...
```

For nesting you go

```
Route::get('/segment/{id}/segment/{id}' ...
```

For optional parameters

```
Route::get('/segment/{id}/segment/{name?}', function($name = null)
```

When it comes to optional stuff, the order you position your routes which contain parameters is imperative.

In my experience the house of cards tends to fall down if you try to use too many parameters without any hard coded prefixes, or use optional parameters in a overly nested way.  Routing is pattern matching at the end of the day.

Im a lazy guy so I would just solve it with

```
Route::get('/publications',...
Route::get('/research-line/{slug}/publications',...
ect ect
```

If you're saying you have to have it specifically as you say, then it looks like it was answered here - 
[Laravel optional routing parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577717/laravel-optional-routing-parameter)

Although I personally not a fan of doing that

Comment: Hi alexander. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, I need the urls to be exactly as I said (customer requirements).
I solved it with multiple routes with closures and direct calls to my actions.
Looks dirty, but I couldn't find a better solution so far.

Comment: @CarlosMaia, no thats fine, having worked under a marketing department in the past, I know you pain in things having to be overly specific. Good to know it all worked out in the end.